# Show Outlook 2016 meetings in Clock & Calendar tray widget

Tags: calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

There is a widget in windows 10 tray which show clock & calendar. There is a section in this widget named Calendar Events for showing events from Windows built-in Calendar app. This is enterpsise PC, so we use Outlook 2016. Is there any way to show events from Outlook 2016 app in this widget?

Comment: I added my enterprise Exchange account intio Win Calendar and now see events in widget, but maybe there is a better way: not to sync 2 apps to one account, but maybe share Outlook 2016 data directly to Win Calendar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, as I know, adding your email account should be the only way to show your calendar items in the widget.

The widget you mentioned is related to the Windows calendar app, and it could only work after you configure your email account to the app.

[image]

But adding my email accounts to both windows calendar and Outlook desktop client also brought some troubles for me, for example Duplicate email notifications. If you got the same issue as me, you could try to disable the app notifications via your Windows notification settings.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.